# JPA java Oracle12cDialect distinct specification compound key don't workl ORA-00909

Tags: oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

i have in my projekt entity with compound key. When i try to use method

```
 Page<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable);
```

everything work's fine but when i add line with distinct to specification

```
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<NotificationSettingsFrontend> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
        query.distinct(true);
```

i get error

```
Caused by: Error : 909, Position : 16, Sql = select distinct count(distinct notificati0_.business_rules_id, notificati0_.notification_config_id) as col_0_0_ from notifications.notification_config_front notificati0_ where 1=1, OriginalSql = select distinct count(distinct notificati0_.business_rules_id, notificati0_.notification_config_id) as col_0_0_ from notifications.notification_config_front notificati0_ where 1=1, Error Msg = ORA-00909: incorrect number of arguments
```

so hibernate generate wrong sql query for count with 2 id's of compound key.
i Use org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect the same is for Oracle10gDialect.
I tried to find a solution at oracle however I can't find a solution to this problem anywhere, I point out that I can't remove the distinct from the code.
Is there a way to change the manual count function or dialect that will solve this problem

Comment: Is this related bug? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1045

Comment: looks like this, unfortunately here is no clear solution to this problem

Comment: I figured this out. I made a little workaround for the problem, and it seems to be working. I just created a view and did something like this: CONCAT(CONCAT(N.NOTIFICATION_CONFIG_ID, '#'), b.BUSINESS_RULES_ID) AS COMPOUND_ID, and I used COMPOUND_ID as the ID for my entity and the same goes for tables i join in specyfication

Answer (score 0):

That's how it works. For example - based on Scott's sample table of employees:

```
SQL> select deptno, ename, job from emp order by deptno, job;

    DEPTNO ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------- ---------
        10 MILLER     CLERK
        10 CLARK      MANAGER
        10 KING       PRESIDENT
        20 SCOTT      ANALYST
        20 FORD       ANALYST
        20 ADAMS      CLERK
        20 SMITH      CLERK
        20 JONES      MANAGER
        30 JAMES      CLERK
        30 BLAKE      MANAGER
        30 MARTIN     SALESMAN
        30 WARD       SALESMAN
        30 ALLEN      SALESMAN
        30 TURNER     SALESMAN

14 rows selected.
```

I can count distinct department numbers:

```
SQL> select count(distinct deptno) from emp;

COUNT(DISTINCTDEPTNO)
---------------------
                    3
```

But, I can't count combination of departments and jobs (basically, that's what you did and error you got):

```
SQL> select count(Distinct deptno, job) from emp;
select count(Distinct deptno, job) from emp
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments
```

A workaround is to e.g. **concatenate** columns. To avoid wrong results (because if you concatenate 12 and 345 you get 12345; you'd get the same if you concatenate 1234 and 5), put character - that doesn't exist in neither of columns, such as # in my example):

```
SQL> select count(distinct deptno ||'#'|| job) from emp;

COUNT(DISTINCTDEPTNO||'#'||JOB)
-------------------------------
                              9
```

I don't know tools you use so I can't suggest exact code, but I hope that what I wrote above makes sense and that you'll be able to use it.

Comment: I understand with sql error, but the problem is that if the query with findAll doesn't return all records, the query using count executes automatically and I don't know how to manage its content to be correct. i use only spring jpa with hibernate